# Handle diverged local and remote feature branches

Tags: git

I've created a feature branch based off of master branch.
This branch has a local copy, as well as a remote copy (need to work on it with other developers).
Master branch has advanced, so I rebased my local feature branch (git rebase master) to catch up with recent updates from master.
However, now my local feature branch and the remote feature branch are diverged - and I can't push to the remote feature branch (unless I use the -f flag).

Is there a way to properly resolve this issue without force pushing?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to properly resolve this issue without force pushing?

You will have to abandon your rebased branch with `git reset --hard origin/master`, which restores your local branch to the state of `master` as it exists on `origin`. Then *merge* master into your branch instead of rebasing, so that your branch's history remains compatible with `origin/master`.

You cannot rebase a branch and still push it without `-f` or `--force`. You're rewriting your local history in a way that makes your branch fundamentally different than the remote branch and everybody else's local branches, and leaves you unable to push your changes. Force-pushing to fix the problem will only introduce problems for everybody else who is currently sharing your branch, and ultimately your commit history will wind up *far* more convoluted than if you simply `git merge origin/master` into your feature branch to keep it up to date.

If you're concerned with a linear history, your best bet is to solve this when you merge your feature branch into `master`, by rebasing or by squashing your commits. Github helps with this, if you're using Github and pull requests to merge change into `master`.

Comment: You *can* `rebase` and force `push` a branch you are sharing (assuming server permissions allow it), your colleagues may not appreciate it though.  Also, if it is a coordinated effort across the team you should be able to do it, or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: @meagar Thanks for your quick reply. Why is reset --hard needed? Can't I just merge master into my local brach (instead of rebasing).  
And in general, isn't merge bad? (the project won't be linear)

Comment: @sergeyrar If you've already rebased, your branch has diverged, and your cleanest way of fixing that is to abandon your rebased branch and return to the current state of `master` as it exists on `origin`. You can just merge `origin/master`, but now you'll have a bunch of duplicated commits caused by a redundant rebase. Merging is not "bad", it's the way Git is supposed to work. You're **supposed** to merge branches into each other. Rebasing for a clean history is a personal preference, but it's not how a distributed VCS like Git is meant to work.

Comment: @Bill You *can* do anything, including coordinating across the team to abandon their local branches, but that's slightly ridiculous in this case. The OP made a small and easily corrected mistake, and should fix their mistake locally, rather than force-push and ask their development team to deal with an `origin/master` that has diverged.

Comment: @meagar Thanks, will do that next time (this time is kind of too late, since I already force pushed :D)

Comment: I would add that, for reasons I don't agree with, many people think merge commits are "ugly" and that only linear histories are "good".  For the workflow you're using (where multiple devs work on feature branches that are apparently fairly long-lived), a linear history isn't really a realistic goal IMO - or at least, it's more trouble than I think it can be worth.  You *can* avoid pushing the merges from master to feature branches - and in fact that's what `git rerere` is meant to help you do. But that basically guarantees you keep "broken" commits around, so again I don't agree with it.